# MYSQL - multiple many to many selection

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, eloquent, entity-attribute-value

I have multiple many to many relations related with one main entity.

Tables (they are different in names, but its easier to demo):

```
products
    - id
    - every other data


colors
    - id
    - every other data

sizes
    - id
    - every other data

product_color
    - product_id
    - color_id

product_size
    - product_id
    - size_id
```

I want to have a number stored somewhere, that I have e.g. 50 pieces of GREEN and XXL sized T-shirt product, but only 20 pieces of green and M sized T-shirt product. Where would I store this number? Is my DB structure efficient for that one at all?  I'm using eloquent + mysql.

Comment: Write out some of the `SELECTs` you will need. -- Let that help you realize how good or bad the schema is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd lose the `product_color` and `product_size` tables, and add a `stock` table with foreign keys to the product, size and color:

```
stock
  - id         -- May be redundant, depends on your application
  - product_id -- FK to products.id
  - color_id   -- FK to colors.id
  - size_id    -- FK to sizes.id
  - amount
```

Comment: A star schema is miserably slow to search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 4 table -

1. products table -  information related to product like name,image,description,status
2. option table -  information related to option like size,color
3. option value - information related to option value like XL, XXL ,RED ,GREEN, BLUE
4. dependent option - for options

```
products
    - product_id (Primary key)
    - every other data
option 
    - option_id (Primary key)
    - option_name(color|size)
option_value
    - option_value_id
    - option_id
    - name

product_option
    - product_id
    - option_id
    - Quantity
Product - 
| product_id | name         |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Tshirt         |
| 2        | Jeans          |


Option
| option_id | option_name   |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 5        | Size           |
| 6        | Color          |


Option_value
| option_value_id | option_id      |option_name| 
| --------        | -------------- |-----------|
| 8               | 5              |   XXL     | 
| 9               | 5              |   L       | 
| 10              | 6              |   RED     |
| 11              | 6              |   BLUE    |



dependent_option
| id | parent_option_value_id| child_option_value_id|   Qty     | 
|----| --------------------- | -------------------- |-----------|
| 1  | 8                     | 10                   |   200     | XXL-RED 
| 2  | 8                     | 11                   |   9       | L-RED
| 3  | 9                     | 10                   |   300     | XXL-BLUE
| 4  | 9                     | 11                   |   4999    | L-BLUE
```

Comment: That's a variant of "Entity-Attribute-Value" which is fraught with issues.